# Outlook not showing rsvp button | not able to parse ics file when it sent from laravel mailable

Tags: laravel, outlook, icalendar

Hi below is my sample ics file which i send using laravel mailable.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//Bookmytime.AI//BOOKMYTIME//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:054ea174cce27588ef8c432603e684c5@bookmytime.ai
DTSTAMP:20240131T093000Z
DTSTART:20240131T093000Z
DTEND:20240131T103000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=jigar halani:mailto:jigar@storat.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;
RSVP=TRUE;mailto:my@outlook.com
DESCRIPTION:Hello be prepared and ready for interview
LOCATION:Delhi
SUMMARY:Interview with test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Outlook is not able to parse this ics and not able to show rsvp button. but gmail is working properly.

```
$markdown->attach($link->formatWith(new \App\Modules\Miscellaneous\Services\BookmytimeICS($options)), ['as' => 'meeting.ics', 'mime' => 'text/calendar'])
```

this is how I am attaching ics file to my mailable.

when I download this file and directly send from my gmail as in attachment its working properly but when it sent from laravel its not showing rsvp button in outlook.

I want below output in outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VCALENDAR should not be one of the MIME parts. It must be the one and only MIME part in the message for Outlook to correctly process it.

Comment: I have same problem as explained here. Could you please exlain this bit more in details.

Comment: I am not sure what it is exactly you want to know. Do you have a specific question?